# Adding user and new machine to Samba server running Rocky Linux

Tags: linux, samba

I'm trying to add a brand new machine onto our network and I'm currently struggling at the moment. A little preface...my network administrator retired a few months ago and my company has no intention to rehire his position so they casually gifted me all of his duties. He left very little documentation. I'm also a programmer and server administration is my weak spot at the moment.

We currently have a file share system running on Rocky Linux which has a Samba server version 4.10.16 running on that Linux server. We do not have an Active Directory. I believe everything is configured in either netBIOS or NT4...whatever the configuration was back in the WinXP days. I added the user to the system by using the useradd command and then adding the user to the appropriate group in the etc/group file. This particular user got a brand new machine that I am now trying to add to the network. I tried adding the machine name into the computers group in the etc/group file and I've tried adding the machine to the passwd file. On the local machine itself I created a user with the exact same name and password as the one on the samba server. When I try to map a drive it gives me an error saying the network password is incorrect. I also moved the lmhosts and hosts file to the new computer.

I feel like I'm missing something else. Something that links the machine and user on the server side.

Comment: This is not my area of expertise either.  You do need to edit / revise smb.conf and edit the sections in the file for sambashare and then set up users with sudo smbpasswd -a <username>   and password  .   There may be more things but these are the items I set up in Samba.   See:   https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#2-installing-samba

Comment: Interesting...I thought I had the password correct but I guess it wasn't. I retyped the password and restarted the samba service and it connected just fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is late but I just came across this questions while looking for a solution myself. I didn't find one here but came up with a work around.

First add the machine account manually by issuing the following commands:

```
useradd -n -c "Workstation (machinename$)" -M -d /nohome -s /bin/false "machinename$"

pdbedit -a -m machinename$
```

After this go ahead and join the domain as you usually would.